# Indexing into a small tuple with an enum index improperly triggers TS2493

Tags: typescript, tslint, deno

The following code is the gist of what I'm trying to do

```
enum Foo {
    Foo0, Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, Foo4 // many more
}

function bar(foo: Foo) {
    const baz: [any, any] = [0,0];

    // Only Foo0 and Foo1 are valid to pass to bar
    if(foo > 2) throw RangeError();
    return baz[foo];
    // ^ Linter gives the following, even though foo can't be greater than 2:
    // TS2493 [ERROR]: Tuple type '[any, any]' of length '2' has no element at index '2'.
    // TS2493 [ERROR]: Tuple type '[any, any]' of length '2' has no element at index '3'.
    // TS2493 [ERROR]: Tuple type '[any, any]' of length '2' has no element at index '4'.
}
```

Because of the line checking the value of `foo`, `baz[foo]` will never be greater than 2. Is there any way I can convince Typescript that it doesn't need to worry about that?

Comment: There is an off-by-one error, by the way. The condition should be `foo > 1` because enums start at 0, unless that was specified differently and that is missing from the example.

Comment: @H.B. The off-by-one is just a typo from distilling my real code for this question. Nice catch though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `enum` keys can be associated with any value, i.e. they do not have to be ascending numbers or start at one specific number, and the compiler does not provide the concrete values there seems to be no way to cleanly handle this.

I would recommend to assert that foo is a number and use that (though that still leaves potential for errors):

```
function bar(foo: Foo) {
    const baz: [any, any] = [0,0];

    const index = foo as number;
    if (index > 1) throw RangeError(); // if enum is 0-based (default)
        return baz[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) can help

```js
enum Foo {
    Foo0, Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, Foo4 // many more
}

function bar(foo: Foo) {
    const baz: [any, any] = [0,0];

    // Only Foo0 and Foo1 are valid to pass to bar
    if(!checkIsFoo0OrFoo1(foo)) throw RangeError();
    return baz[foo];
}

function checkIsFoo0OrFoo1(foo: Foo): foo is (Foo.Foo0 | Foo.Foo1) {
  return foo > 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not use `Enum` for such purpose.

just use `0|1` index union type for `foo` argument

```js
type Foo = 0|1

function bar(foo: Foo) {
    const baz: [any, any] = [0,0];
    return baz[foo];
}
```

Comment: The Foo enum has more meaning than indicated here, it was just distilled for this question. I know it's not generally good practice, but I promise there's a good reason to use it instead of just 0|1|etc.